Python Creating chunks of val from given cap number
I am creating a list of a certain value given a cap number and I can do this using the following. I am just wondering if there is a better/shorter/faster way to do this.
cap = 93
chunkSize = 10
chunks = []
while cap > 0: 
    val = chunkSize if cap / chunkSize >= 1 else cap
    chunks.append(val)
    cap -= val

for i, q in enumerate(chunks):
    print(i, q)

And the expected and correct output is -
0 10
1 10
2 10
3 10
4 10
5 10
6 10
7 10
8 10
9 3

If there is some fancy way to do this, please reply.
I already have a working solution.

What you are doing is basically a roundabout way to perform division with a remainder:
chunks = [chunkSize] * (cap // chunkSize) + [cap % chunkSize]

As noted by viggo, just calculate how many whole chunks you need. The difference is only that you need to check if the last chunk is not zero:
# divmod: same as whole_chunks, last_chunk = cap // chunk_size, cap % chunk_size
whole_chunks, last_chunk = divmod(cap, chunk_size)
chunks = [chunk_size] * whole_chunks
if last_chunk:
    chunks.append(last_chunk)


Thank you, python amateur here... didn't even know there was something called divmod
